# wpf image viewer path

Tags: .net, wpf, xaml, wpf-controls

I would like to make an image viewer where the client can load thumbnails to a file, then when the Photo Gallery button is selected the thumbnails appear in a grid and when the thumbnail is selected a larger photo will show in a viwbox. How do I get the path for the button click event to the photos? Can this be done in a markup ext?

Answer (score 0):

I assume you already have thumbnails created on the file system, something like this:

```
\Folder\Image1.png
\Folder\Image1-Thumb.png
\Folder\Image2.png
\Folder\Image2-Thumb.png
```

I would load that into a list of a custom class, maybe a ViewModel that had two properties for Image and ImageThumb -- then you can setup WPF Bindings accordingly.

Comment: thank you Nate, I'm not really sure how to set up the folder because the user will add the photos at runtime.

Comment: Folder is simply a place-holder. As long as you have a database of where every 'main' image is, you can generate a thumbnail right next to it and store that in your database as well.